# Python script using xlwings fails to open Excel workbook when run from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, xlwings, windows-task-scheduler

Windows 10
xlwings 0.30.8,
Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (ver 2302 16.0.16130.20586) 32 bit,
Python 3.9.12

Describe your issue (incl. Traceback!)
I am experiencing a problem with my Python script that uses the xlwings library to open and work with Excel workbooks.

When I run my script directly from the command line, everything works perfectly. However, when I run the script as a scheduled task using Windows Task Scheduler, the script fails to open the workbook.

Here is the part of my code that is causing the issue:

```
app = xw.App(visible=False)
workbook = app.books.open(OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE)
```

The script successfully runs the first line, but fails to execute the second line that tries to open the workbook. When the script fails to open the workbook, it does not raise an error and the execution just halts.

To debug this issue, I have added logging messages in the open method of the xlwings Book class in the xlwings library source code. From the logs, it appears that the execution halts at the self.impl.open(...) call in the open method.

The KeyError is raised when the code tries to find an already open workbook with the same name as the one we are trying to open (impl = self.impl(name)). The exception is caught and execution should proceed to opening the workbook, but it doesn't.

I am unsure of why the script is unable to open the workbook when run from the Task Scheduler, but has no issues when run from the command line.

I have ensured that the workbook path (OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE) is correct and that the workbook is not already open.

Any advice on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

The relevant part of the script is as follows.
logger.debug('openedbook___' + OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE)
Debugging output for the line is done, but the next line is executed, but the process does not progress.

```
import sqlite3 
import datetime import xlwings as xw
import debuglog as logger

data_start_row = 11 employee_no_col = 3

def update_overtime_in_excel(config, OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE): DB_FILE = config['DB_FILE'] EXTRA_INF = config['EXTRA_INF']

# Connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
c = conn.cursor()
today = datetime.datetime.today()

# Start Excel application and open the workbook
logger.debug('openbook___' + OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE)
app = xw.App(visible=False)

logger.debug('app___' + OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE)
workbook = app.books.open(OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE)

logger.debug('openedbook___' + OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE)

# Process each sheet for each month
for sheet in workbook.sheets:
```

When I debugged the following comment in xlwings main.py,
'open5' is printed and
Both 'Failed to open workbook with name' and 'Error details' output the target file name (only the file name that is not the full path) and stop processing.

```
def open(
    self,
    fullname=None,
    update_links=None,
    read_only=None,
    format=None,
    password=None,
    write_res_password=None,
    ignore_read_only_recommended=None,
    origin=None,
    delimiter=None,
    editable=None,
    notify=None,
    converter=None,
    add_to_mru=None,
    local=None,
    corrupt_load=None,
    json=None,
):

    """
    Opens a Book if it is not open yet and returns it. If it is already open,
    it doesn't raise an exception but simply returns the Book object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fullname : str or path-like object
        filename or fully qualified filename, e.g. ``r'C:\\path\\to\\file.xlsx'``
        or ``'file.xlsm'``. Without a full path, it looks for the file in the
        current working directory.

    Other Parameters
        see: :meth:`xlwings.Book()`

    Returns
    -------
    Book : Book that has been opened.

    """
    logger.debug('open1')
    if self.impl.app.engine.type == "remote":
        return Book(impl=self.impl.open(json=json))

    fullname = utils.fspath(fullname)

    logger.debug('open2')

    if not os.path.exists(fullname):
        raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fullname)
    fullname = os.path.realpath(fullname)
    _, name = os.path.split(fullname)

    logger.debug('open3')

    if self.impl.app.engine.type == "reader":
        return Book(impl=self.impl.open(filename=fullname))

    logger.debug('open4')

    try:
        impl = self.impl(name)
        if not os.path.samefile(impl.fullname, fullname):
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot open two workbooks named '%s', even if they are saved in"
                "different locations." % name
            )
    except KeyError as e:
        logger.debug('open5')
        logger.debug('Failed to open workbook with name: %s', name)
        logger.debug('Error details: %s', e)

        impl = self.impl.open(
            fullname,
            update_links,
            read_only,
            format,
            password,
            write_res_password,
            ignore_read_only_recommended,
            origin,
            delimiter,
            editable,
            notify,
            converter,
            add_to_mru,
            local,
            corrupt_load,
        )
        
        logger.debug('open6')

    return Book(impl=impl)
```

Comment: There is nothing in the the two lines provided that need to be changed they will work. You might need to try with a simple program first like open workbook/worksheet and print a cell value. Have the script running the python file direct the output to another file and check that works. Usually the issue is the path but you're absolutely sure it's OK. Not much else I can suggest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.